# Rails3: count does not equal length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Today a user pointed out to me that one of the reports in my Rails3 app has a count of records at top and it did not match the number of records in the report.

The report shows [object].count at the top and then starts a table and does an [object].each to create the rows in the table. A row is created for every loop of the #each; none are skipped. Yet the count does not match the number of rows. Note that this is in my dev instance, so no new records are being created.

I ran it down to this scope:

```
scope :by_reviewer, lambda {|reviewer| includes([:task]).joins(:work_assignments).where('work_assignments.reviewer = ?', reviewer).uniq }
```

It's the uniq that's doing it. The [object].count reports the *total count* in the database (there may be more than one work_assignment per task), but when I loop, I get only the unique ones.

Is this a bug, or what? I fixed it by calling length instead, which returns the right number (the number in the [object]).

I know #count always goes back to the database, but even so, why is the #uniq dropped when this happens? If the object is created from this scope, and then #count wants to query again, shouldn't that re-query include the #uniq?